# Subfloor patching

Tags: flooring

[image]

This is picture of door opening where my dining room (laminate) floor meets kitchen vinyl. I recently created door opening in wall and now I am planning to install new vinyl flooring on kitchen side.(bottom side of picture). My question is how can i fill dents and level the subfloor where 2 floors will meet before installing floor and transition strip. What should I use to fill and level ?

Comment: A profile drawing would be helpful'

Comment: Will you be removing the old vinyl  or install new vinyl over old?

Comment: Install a new vinyl over old which is in pretty good condition

Answer (score 1):

If this is under a door, then a simple answer may be to just install a threshold or "junction", typically a metal strip used to join a carpeted floor to a non-carpeted floor, or when two types of mis-matched carpet meet. These "junctions" could be lumber, sheet metal, sheet copper or brass, or something more stylishly related to your home.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fill it with whatever wood and plywood you have on hand, then skim with a leveler designed for vinyl floor preparation. Any home improvement store can suggest one.